# is it possible to encrypt 10 digit number to 4 digit number using any algorithm?

Tags: java

Example 10 digit number 9898989898 this should be encrypt to 4 or 6 digit number after that if i decrypt that 4 or 6 digit number its same as 9898989898. Is their any algorithm to do this please help me on this

Comment: It's called cmpression

Comment: You can encrypt 10 digits into 4 bytes but not 4 numbers: just look at the binary representation.

Comment: There is no algorithm that can compress an arbitrary 10 digit number to 4 digits.

Comment: If your 10 digit number is base 10 and your 6 digit number is base 47 or greater, you can. 47^6 is 10779215329. Not even using 10 digits and 26 English letters will suffice for encoding. If you additionally distinguish between uppercase and lowercase, you’re there, but I wouldn’t call it a *6 digit number* anymore, rather a 6 character alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 7):

I would say no: because of [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you do not have enough 4-6 digit numbers to "decrypt" back univocally to your original 10 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

You need an alphabet with at least 47 characters in order to encode 10 digits with 6 characters. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2010%5E10%20%3C%3D%20x%5E6,%20x%20%3E%200%20over%20the%20integers).

[image]